# Cayley's theorem and unique groups of particular order?

Tags: group-theory

We have groups of prime order that are unique for that order as well as groups of order $pq$ where $p,q$ are prime and $p \nmid (q-1)$ that are unique. However, Cayley's theorem shows that there's a symmetric group that is isomorphic to that group.

So shouldn't there be at least 2 groups rather than 1 unique group for those specific orders (the group itself and another $S_n$ group)?

Comment: Every group is isomoprhic to a SUBGROUP of a symmetric group , not to a symmetric group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cayley's theorem shows that there is a *subgroup* of a symmetric group that is isomorphic to that group, and in your cases that subgroup happens to be cyclic.